# Postage Stamp Vending Machine

Tags: java, oop

I was given an assignment to develop an algorithm for dispensing stamps for a postage
stamp vending machine. I need to write a function that will return the minimum number of stamps for a
given value. We can assume that there will always be a one cent stamp in the machine.

The function prototype looks like:

```
int min_number_of_stamps (
const int* array, /* input array of sorted stamp values */
size_t array_size, /* number of elements in array */
int request /* desired value to of stamps */
);
```

The function will return the minimum number of stamps for a given
value. As an example, if the array was `[90,30,24,15,12,10,5,3,2,1]` and the
request was `32`, the output should be `2`, `one 30 cent stamp` and `one 2
cent stamp`.

Could anyone help me solve this question or give me some hint to do it?

Comment: You start with the first stamp value (highest) and keep going until you can find a stamp value less than the request. Then you simply add that stamp to an array, subtract from the request and repeat until the request is zero.

Comment: I would suggest coming up with a general algorithm to solve the problem first, *then* worrying about how to program it in Java. As the questions reads now, it sounds like you basically want all the work done for you.

Comment: @RiverC Say your denominations are [90, 80, 70, 1]. And your request is 140. Going by what you've suggested, I'd get 90 + (50 x 1). I would expect to get 70 + 70.

Answer (score 4):

You've certainly got a good start: you'll need an array.

Two differences from C/C++:

1) You don't need an "array_size": Java arrays "know" how long they are

2) You can't declare "const int* array".  Instead, you must specify "int[] array" ... then initialize it.

Here's a good link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

PS:

Here's a skeleton for a Java class you might consider:

```
public class StampVendingMachine {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    // Your program starts in this method...
  }

  public int minStamps (int num_stamps) {
    // This is where you can compute how many stamps 
  }

  // This can be your "lookup table"
  private int[] min_number_of_stamps;
}
```

PPS:

One other link:

[Maximum value of postage stamps on an envelope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826975/algorithm-for-postage-stamp-problem)

Comment: Thank you so much for the response! These are really helpful and make sense to me. I think I am heading to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework:

> I am a new beginner in Java and wonder if anyone could help me solve this question

If you mean ... "provide me with a solution" ... that is clearly inappropriate, and not in your long term interest.

> ... or give me some hint to do it.

OK.

1. From the algorithmic side, think about how you would do it tell a 6 year old to do it ... assuming that he/she who didn't understood how to multiply and divide.  RiverC's comment is a good place to start.
2. You don't seem to have a grasp of the basics of the Java language:

   - While the syntax is *similar* in many ways, Java is very different from C or C++.  Don't expect that your C / C++ knowledge will carry over to Java.  For instance:

     - Java doesn't have functions, it has methods.
     - Java's array declaration *and initialization* syntax is different to C / C++'s.
     - Java arrays are semantically different to C / C++'s in some important respects.
   - To get you started, you either need to read the first few chapters of a good Java text book (e.g. the one recommended by your Java lecturer), or read the Oracle Java Tutorial.  If you skip this step, I predict that you will struggle.  (And if you don't have time because your assignment deadline is looming, it is pretty much a certainty ...)